# MVC Kendo Chart Series Error in Google Chrome console VM1574:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'totalCC')

Tags: kendo-chart

I have encountered an error in the MVC Kendo Chart Series and it is showing up on the Google Chrome console as follows: VM1574:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total'). After investigating the issue, we have found that this error occurs when two values from the series are equal. It appears that the Kendo chart series is unable to distinguish between two different series that have the same value.

I have encountered an error in the MVC Kendo Chart Series, and it is showing up on the Google Chrome console as follows: VM1574:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total'). After investigating the issue, we have found that this error occurs when two values from the series are equal. It appears that the Kendo chart series is unable to distinguish between two different series that have the same value.

We expect that the Chart prints out correctly if the series is different and values could be the same.